# Why does pointer arithmetic gives an error when assigned to direct array

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying a code with pointer arithmetic, but it seems to give error.

The pointer `*p` to arr gives desired output with pointer arithmetic, but when i do the same with `*k`, it gives an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
    int *p=arr;
    int *k={1,2,3,4};
    printf("%d",*arr+2);
    printf("%d",*k+2);
}
```

I expect that `*k+2` gives exact same output as `*arr+2`, but it doesn't happen that way. What's the possible reason

Comment: Build with warnings enabled and read about the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator), because `int *k={1,2,3,4};` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers are not arrays and you can not use the same syntax to initialize them, in the first case `p` *points* to the address of the first element of the array while in the second one you are assigning `1` (the first value of the list) as a value to the pointer, in consequence `k` *points* to the address `0x01` and since you are not allowed to dereference this address you get an error (probably a segmentation fault).

```
demo.c:7:5: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
     int *k={1,2,3,4};
     ^
```

But since C99 we can use compound literals, compound literals allows us to create unnamed objects with given list of initialized values, in other words: you can use a cast to an array as initializer.

In this way:

```
int *k= (int []){1,2,3,4};
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing int *k={1,2,3,4}; you are basically declaring a pointer to an int and then initialising it like an array, the syntax is not correct.